# Colorbox in powerline style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I want to add colorboxes in my latex document based on the powerline style in the image. How can it be achieved, a simple example using tcolorbox or tikz package would work.

[image]

Comment: You should probably have a look at the `menukeys` package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! There is no really big obstacle in creating this with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,chains,shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily,start chain=A going right,
    node distance=1ex,
    nodes={minimum height=1.6em,on chain,text depth=0.25ex},
    pp/.style={append after command={
    ([yshift=0.2ex]\tikzlastnode.south east) 
        edge[gray!20,line cap=rect,semithick]
     ([xshift=1ex]\tikzlastnode.east)
    ([yshift=-0.2ex]\tikzlastnode.north east) 
        edge[gray!20,line cap=rect,semithick]
     ([xshift=1ex]\tikzlastnode.east)
     }},
    show background rectangle,inner frame sep=0.5ex,
    background rectangle/.style={fill=black}]
  \path node[signal,fill=green!60,signal from=nowhere,signal to=east]{N}
  node[xshift=-1.1ex,signal,fill=gray!10,signal from=west,
      signal to=east](pedro){pedro}
  [text=gray!20]
  node {\Large\faGithub}
  node{master}
  node[text=red!50]{+1}
  node[pp]{\faFolderOpen}
  [node distance=2ex]
  node[pp]{git-repos}
  node[pp]{private};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]